# Apache Derby Like clause with boolean expression error

Tags: derby

I am trying to run the following query to Apache Derby Embedded DB

select  ProjectName , CompaignNumber ,JobNumber from arcproject
    where  Projectname like '%'  OR CompaignNumber like '%' OR JobNumber like  '%'

but it creates the following error

```
ERROR: No authorized routine named 'LIKE' of type 'FUNCTION'
having compatible arguments was found.
Error Code: 30000
```

I am unable to understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you didn't include the *exact* syntax of your program in your question, because when I cut-and-pasted your query into Derby it worked fine:

```
ij> create table arcproject (ProjectName varchar(10),CompaignNumber varchar(10),JobNumber varchar(10));
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
ij> insert into arcproject values ('a','b','c');
1 row inserted/updated/deleted
ij> select ProjectName , CompaignNumber ,JobNumber from arcproject where Projectname like '%' OR CompaignNumber like '%' OR JobNumber like '%';
PROJECTNA&|COMPAIGNN&|JOBNUMBER
--------------------------------
a         |b         |c
```

Remember, when asking a question, it is crucial that you include *all* the details, including the *exact* syntax you used, particularly when you are asking about a syntax error.

Comment: I posted the detail program below. Please check it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First thanks for your reply. Now I am sending the every detail(The queries give below are working queries).

First I created the table with the query

CREATE TABLE "APP"."ARCPROJECT"(
PROJECTNAME VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY not null,
COMPAIGNNUMBER VARCHAR default 'NULL',
JOBNUMBER INTEGER default 'NULL',
RESPONSIBLEPERSON VARCHAR not null,
PROJECTSTARTDATE DATE default 'NULL',
PROJECTENDDATE DATE default 'NULL')

Then I inserted the values

insert into "APP"."ARCPROJECT" (PROJECTNAME, COMPAIGNNUMBER, JOBNUMBER, RESPONSIBLEPERSON, PROJECTSTARTDATE, PROJECTENDDATE) values ('proje-1', 'cmp-123', 89, 'person-xyz', '2012-12-8', '2013-12-8');

Then when I try this query it gave me the same error I mentioned above.

select ProjectName , CompaignNumber ,JobNumber, Responsibleperson,ProjectStartDate, projectEndDate 
       from arcproject 
       where Projectname like '%' OR CompaignNumber like '%' OR JobNumber like '%' OR Responsibleperson like '%';

Note : When I take only two OR expression (e.g. "where Projectname like '%' OR CompaignNumber like '%'") then it works fine but when I add another one it start showing error message mentioned before.

Comment: You could have edited your question rather than posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the update; it is clearer now.

What version of Derby are you using? I was unable to run your CREATE TABLE statement as is; I had to make two changes:
1) I had to change "VARCHAR" to "VARCHAR(10)"
2) I had to change "INTEGER default 'NULL'" to "INTEGER default 0"

After I did those two changes, I get the message that you described.

The problem is with the JOBNUMBER column, which you have declared as INTEGER.

You cannot use 'LIKE' on an "INTEGER" column; it only works on strings

If you change your SELECT statement from "JobNumber like '%'" to "JobNumber != 0", then the statement works fine.

I agree that the message is not very clear; I will open an issue at the Derby project to try to improve the message, because I think it could have been much clearer for you.

You can follow the results of that issue here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-6020

Comment: Great thanks for your reply. I am using derby version 10.8.1. I also check and try query according to your analysis and if I will find something I will update the forum. Thanks again.